# file download Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream

Tags: php, download, mime

I have an iframe in the page which I use for file download. I set iframe source pointing to this php file with mp3 song path and tile.

```
<?php 
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    $name = $_GET['name'];
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$name\"");
    $path = str_replace(' ', '%20', $_GET['path']);
    readfile($path);
    exit;
?>
```

When  I try to download mp3 song from audio player on this site:

http://janeingalls.com/

I get this message in console and file size is always 0 bytes when downloaded.

```
Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream
```

Answer (score -1):

Add a header to tell the browser how big the file is after you know its path:

```
...
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path));
readfile($path);
exit;
```